# How can I create an animated palette (color cycling) animation in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, animation, graphics, firemonkey, palette

An old-school graphics effect is palette animation, where for an image of (say) 256 colours, the palette that each color index of 0-255 refers to is shifted.  As it shifts, the colours of each pixel change.

[You can read more about the technique here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_cycling) and see a fantastic [HTML5 reproduction of old-style effects here](http://www.effectgames.com/demos/canvascycle/?sound=1).  Here is a plasma example from Wikipedia:

[image: Color cycling from Wikipedia]

**I would like to achieve the same effect in FireMonkey,** using FMX `TBitmap`s or another inbuilt class. (I currently have `TBitmap`s - with static colours - built once-off from a table of values.) FMX is quite abstracted from the underlying OS, and also using underlying OS techniques will stop the app being cross-platform-compatible. On the other hand, since it uses DirectX or OpenGL under the hood, fast animation effects should be very possible. What's the best approach?

I am using Delphi XE2 (original FireMonkey) but a technique for anything up to XE4 (FMX 3) is fine too.

Comment: I believe that all modern graphics hardware uses a native RGBA (32 bit) representation inside the video card, there is no longer any palette left for you to "shift".  You could generate a "particle effect" that looks like your example, but I doubt that you could directly emulate the exact palette-shift. You could however probably create an animation and put that in as a texture.

Comment: A particle effect? Could you expand on that please? Possible ideas I had for how to do this include trying to create a 256-colour bitmap, and have a filter or shader every time it was drawn to the screen.  Or, if I keep my table data and rebuild the bitmap image every animation tick step (that seems a *lot* of processing though.) Or...

Comment: Well your sample animation shows something that looks like a wave of particles, spreading, colliding, and gathering.  By particle effect I mean you would simulate each dot in the image you wish to create, and these dots would interact (be entangled, attracted, repelled) by some set of rules you developed.

Comment: A wide variety of shader examples here but I believe these are OpenGL not Firemonkey:

https://code.google.com/p/delphi-shader/

Comment: Ok - thanks, but that example is just an example. The link includes examples of many other images made using the same technique. As for shaders, I remembered FMX can also use the GDI+ canvas, which has no shader support...